# Use of undeclared identifier 'kABNicknameProperty' in iOS AddressBook - why?

Tags: ios, ios5, compiler-errors, addressbook, abaddressbook

I'm trying to **fetch the name and birth date of an address book entry on iOS (5.0+)** and I found a way of doing so with the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH3-SW6) and [this post](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/44747-iphone-address-book-get-person-by-name.html). But **I always get the error mentioned in the title for all the 'kAB...' constants** although I'm sure I linked the two libraries AddressBook and AddressBookUI in my project.

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Here's my code:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

// some other code ...

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    NSString *name;

    if ((NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABNicknameProperty) != nil) {
        name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABNicknameProperty);
    } else if ((NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABFirstNameProperty) != nil) {
        name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABFirstNameProperty);
    } else if ((NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABLastNameProperty) != nil) {
        name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABLastNameProperty);
    }

    int birthYear;
    if ((NSDate *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABBirthdayProperty) != nil) {
        NSDate *birthDate = (NSDate *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABBirthdayProperty) != nil;
        NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] init];
        NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:0 fromDate:birthDate];
        birthYear = [components year];
    }

    // do something with name and birth year
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the constants you're using are specific to Mac OS X.  The iOS documentation for its version of `ABRecordCopyValue` leads to constant names such as `kABPersonNicknameProperty`.

Comment: Thanks! So I forgot the 'Person' in the constant names - didn't see this. Now it's all working as expected (although there are still some issues with type conversion ... but I'll work them out). :)